# Swift - Present another view controller with its navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, navigationbar

I have two ViewControllers -- one with storyboard and one without. Both of those view controllers have their own Navigation Bar at the top. Now when I use `self.presentViewController(editorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` my editorViewController comes up but without its Navigation bar.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Vasil, for your question you just deleted, try looking at Toucan: https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I fixed the problem using the following code:

```
let editorViewController = IMGLYMainEditorViewController()
let navEditorViewController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editorViewController)
self.presentViewController(navEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I just added the `navEditorViewController` as it made my navigation bar with its items to appear.

Comment: But the presented UIViewController doesn't have a Back button. How to handle that ?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah when you present a new navigation controller, your previous navigation stack get removed. if you need to show back button, then you have to present view controller, not a navigation controller.

Answer (score 9):

Try `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(...)`

Comment: Probably because you haven't used a Navigation Controller. Can you show me your storyboard?

Comment: Here is my storyboard http://postimg.org/image/5x0bszdlf/ when i press Edit the image editor editorViewController should pop up

Comment: Sorry if I insist.. So your storyboard only has that view controller??

Comment: I think you should use a NavigationController. Look here: http://postimg.org/image/byfh6263r/

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5+**

```
let destinationNavigationController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav") as! UINavigationController
destinationNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen        
self.present(destinationNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here your navigation bar replaces with new navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

So for everyone still curious about this problem, given that we already have existing **`UINavigationController`** other than the **current** one:

**Swift 3**

First, we need to find the **`UIViewController`** that we want to present:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewController") as! DestinationViewController
```

Next, we're doing the same thing for **`UINavigationController`**:

```
let destinationNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
```

Then, we want to bring the **`DestinationViewController`** to the top of our destination **`UINavigationController`** stack:

```
destinationNavigationController.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
```

Finally, just present destination **`UINavigationController`**:

```
self.present(destinationNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```